# Почему всплывает ошибка 404 при переходе на страницу удаления поста или тэга?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, url, http-status-code-404

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
urlpatterns = [
    path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),
    path('post/create/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post_create_url'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/update', PostUpdate.as_view(), name='post_update_url'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/delete/>', PostDelete.as_view(), name='post_delete_url'),
    path('tags/', tags_list, name='tags_list_url'),
    path('tag/create/', TagCreate.as_view(), name='tag_create_url'),
    path('tag/<str:slug>/', TagDetail.as_view(), name='tag_detail_url'),
    path('tag/<str:slug>/update/', TagUpdate.as_view(), name='tag_update_url'),
    path('tag/<str:slug>/delete/>', TagDelete.as_view(), name='tag_delete_url')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import View
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Post, Tag
from .utils import *
from .forms import TagForm, PostForm


def posts_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})

def tags_list(request):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})

class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
    model = Post
    template = 'blog/post_detail.html'

class PostCreate(ObjectCreateMixin, View):
    model_form = PostForm
    template = 'blog/post_create_form.html'

class PostUpdate(ObjectUpdateMixin, View):
    model =Post
    model_form = PostForm
    template = 'blog/post_update_form.html'

class PostDelete(ObjectDeleteMixin, View):
    model = Post
    template = 'blog/post_delete_form.html'
    redirect_url = 'posts_list_url'

class TagDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
    model = Tag
    template = 'blog/tag_detail.html'

class TagCreate(ObjectCreateMixin, View):
    model_form = TagForm
    template = 'blog/tag_create.html'

class TagUpdate(ObjectUpdateMixin, View):
    model = Tag
    model_form = TagForm
    template = 'blog/tag_update_form.html'

class TagDelete(ObjectDeleteMixin, View):
    model = Tag
    template = 'blog/tag_delete_form.html'
    redirect_url = 'tags_list_url'
```

**utils.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import *

class ObjectDetailMixin:
    model = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request, slug):
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
        return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})

class ObjectCreateMixin:
    model_form = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.model_form()
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = self.model_form(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_object = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_object)
        return render(request, self.template, content={'form': bound_form})

class ObjectUpdateMixin:
    model = None
    model_form = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        bound_form = self.model_form(instance=obj)
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': bound_form, self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})

    def post(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        bound_form = self.model_form(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_tag = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_tag)
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': bound_form, self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})

class ObjectDeleteMixin:
    model = None
    template = None
    redirect_url = None
    def get(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})

    def post(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        obj.delete()
        return redirect(reverse(self.redirect_url))
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from time import time

def gen_slug(s):
    new_slug = slugify(s, allow_unicode=True)
    return new_slug + '-' + str(int(time()))

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)#Может быть пустым
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('post_update_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('post_delete_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = gen_slug(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('tag_update_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('tag_delete_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**tag_delete_form.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base_blog.html' %}

{% block title %}
  Delete Tag - {{ tag.title|title }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
  <form action="{{tag.get_delete_url}}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Are you sure you want to delete <b>"{{ tag.title|title }}"</b> tag ?</h3>
    <a href="{% url 'tag_detail_url' slug=tag.slug %}">Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

[image: Тэг что я хочу удалить]

[image: При переходе на страницу удаления возникает ошибка]

[image: Не заходит в нужный метод]

[image: Дерево каталогов]

Comment: А где Вы передаёте `tag` в шаблон?

Comment: utils.py;
Класс: class ObjectDeleteMixin;
Функция get;
obj - и есть мой tag;

Дочерний класс TagDelete в файле views.py ;
Вот здесь я присваиваю объект Tag - model = Tag

Comment: Потому что вы переходите по адресу `delete/`, но согласно urls.py вы должны переходить на `delete/>`